# Vistas en Fragment Android Studio (ProgressBar)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, progressbar

Tengo un Problema, en mi código. Lo que quiero es que al presionar un botón se realice una consulta a una Base de Datos SQL Server, pero que en el lapso de tiempo de ésta consulta se muestre un ProgressBar.

El problema radica que mi ProgressBar nunca se muestra. Dejo el código.

Progressbar en el layout.

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbCargando"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:backgroundTint="#D2040303"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Declarando el ProgressBar

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_excepciones, container, false);
    //ProgressBar
    pb = (ProgressBar) vista.findViewById(R.id.pbCargando);

    return vista;

}
```

Método en donde se quiere utilizar el progressBar

```
 private void validarNCAH(Integer seleccion, View v) {
    if (edtNroCahPtm.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        Snackbar.make(v, "Necesito el numero de caja de ahorro para esa opcion...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) (getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
        input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);//OCULTAR EL TECLADO EN PANTALLA PARA VER LOS MENSAJES
    } else {
      
        pb.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE); //Mostrar el ProgressBar hasta que terminen las consultas a la BD
        
        existeNroCAH(v);

    }
```

El código del método existeNroCAH()

```
    private void existeNroCAH(View v) {
    Connection conn = conexion();
    try {
        Integer nroCah = Integer.parseInt(edtNroCahPtm.getText().toString().trim());//Se obtiene el num de caja de ahorro ingresado
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cahmst_maestro WHERE nro_cuenta = " + nroCah + " AND indicador ='A'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            //Si existen registros
            //Snackbar.make(v, "La caja de AHORRO EXISTE :v", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            try {
                Statement stm2 = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs2 = stm2.executeQuery("select cli.cliente, cli.nombre_ful  FROM climst_cliente cli,cahmst_maestro cah,climst_clioper clioper WHERE cah.nro_cuenta   = " + nroCah + " " +
                        "AND cah.indicador    = 'A' " +
                        "AND cah.nro_cuenta   = clioper.nro_cuenta " +
                        "and clioper.sistema  = 200 " +
                        "and clioper.tipo_rel = 4 " +
                        "and clioper.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050' " +
                        "and clioper.cliente  = cli.cliente " +
                        "and cli.indicador    = 'A' " +
                        "and cli.fecha_proceso_hasta = '01-01-2050'");

                if (rs2.next()) {
                    String numSocio = rs2.getString(1);//Se obtiene el num de socio de la BD
                    String nombre = rs2.getString(2);//Se obtiene el nombre de la BD

                    txtNombreCahPtmo.setText(numSocio + "   " + nombre);//Se muestra el socio y el nombre en pamtalla
                    pb.setVisibility(v.INVISIBLE); //Ocultar el ProgressBar cuando terminen las consultas a la BD
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "NADA ENCONTRADO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "EROR EN LA CONSULTA 2 cah" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else {
            Snackbar.make(v, "El Numero de Caja de ahorro ingresado NO EXISTE. Verifique!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            txtNombreCahPtmo.setText("");//Limpiar nombre
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "EROR EN LA CONSULTA1 cah" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

He estado haciendo algunas pruebas y me he dado cuenta que primero se ejecuta el método existeNroCAH() y después la línea de código en donde se hace visible el ProgressBar, pero no logro entender porqué.
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Muéstranos el layout donde defines tu ProgessBar, así como la parte del código (Java) donde lo estás declarando, supongo que es desde una Activity o un Fragment, aunque no veamos la clase completa, conviene al menos que veamos qué tipo de elemento es y desde qué método declaras el objeto `pb`. Y, dado que hay condicionales, depura que el código entra en los bloques donde el ProgressBar se mostraría.

Comment: Ya actualicé la formulación de la pregunta con lo que me está solicitando. Espero sea entendible.

Comment: Otra cosa que me parece extraña es tu consulta a la base de datos ¿? ¿Ese código funciona realmente? Android suele usar Room para trabajar con bases de datos embebidas, mientras que tu código parece estar basado en JDBC.

Comment: OK, el ProgressBar está bien referenciado. Pero no veo cómo, desde el `onCreateView` llamas a los otros métodos ¿? Y, como te dije en mi comentario anterior, me extraña que un código basado en JDBC funcione en Android. ¿Esa consulta trae datos realmente? ¿O ese código hace referencia a código en el servidor? Eso explicaría que el pb se muestre primero, porque la consulta a la base de datos sería asíncrona (si estás consultando en un servidor). Es un detalle fundamental del que no dices absolutamente nada en tu pregunta.

Comment: Sí, el código funciona bien todo. Estoy programando en JAVA, no en Kotlin. Enseguida pongo como llamo el onClick al presionar el botón.

Comment: Supongo que si funciona tú estarías conectando a la Base de Datos mediante una dirección IP o algo así. Esa llamada sería asíncrona, es decir, no sabes en qué momento exacto la conexión a la BD se realizará y los datos serán devueltos. Por otra parte, esa llamada podría estar bloqueando el hilo principal, lo cual es totalmente desaconsejado por Android. Este tipo de operaciones suelen hacerse pidiendo los datos a través de un servicio web, usando Retrofit o Volley y observando la respuesta, para actualizar la UI cuando la misma haya sido procesada.

Comment: Es correcto. Ocupo un método de conexión a la BD mediante una ip.

Comment: Es ineficiente hacer esto?

Comment: Sí, es ineficiente y es una práctica totalmente desaconsejada. Todas las tareas que tardan X tiempo no deberían nunca bloquear el hilo principal. Debes usar un elemento observable, así serás notificado cuando la tarea se complete, pasando entonces a actualizar la UI. Tú puedes hacer esto mediante Retrofit+RXJava, combinando con [la clase `LiveData` de Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata?hl=es-419). Lo que pasa es que hablamos de algo totalmente nuevo: programación reactiva, y no es tan simple de entender al principio.

Comment: Otra aspecto importante es que, no es lo mismo conectarte a una BD desde el cliente de Android, que conectarte a la base de datos en su ámbito natural (el servidor). Imagina que la BD está en un servidor remoto, y que la conexión a internet está lenta, o el servidor está lento ... y encima de eso te estás conectando desde el cliente a la base de datos. Lo propio es programar un servicio web en el servidor, que se conecte a la BD, y te traiga los datos en un formato ligero (JSON es lo más usado). Desde Android pedirías los datos por una URL, mediante Retrofit. Esa es la forma habitual.

Comment: Gracias, voy a investigar más al respecto.

Comment: Lo que yo entiendo es q para lograr esto debes hacer tareas asincronas ya sea con coroutinas o con Async task pq de lo contrario se bloquea tu UI por usar el MainThread.

Comment: Lo solucioné usando AsyncTask. Gracias.